# E-Mail Existence Check in C#

Tags: c#

I want to verify whether an e-mail is real or not. Some body told me I could do it with DNS check but I don't know how to do this.

Could somebody help me through this problem and I am developing with C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess this code-project article gives you the information you want: [Effective Email Address Validation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/Valid_Email_Addresses.aspx)

But even if you confirm that a domain is valid, it is still not guaranteed that the email address/recipient is valid. E.g. "xyz@stackoverflow.com" -> the domain is valid, but "xyz" might not be a valid email address.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DNS to determine if a *domain* is valid/resolving.  That wouldn't necessarily mean that a given email address at that domain is valid.  The only way to know that is to open an SMTP connection and try to send mail to that user.

Answer (score 2):

Never done this myself, but there appears to be a pretty good C# walkthrough [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/Valid_Email_Addresses.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

DNS check would imply parsing out the domain attached to the email address in question and making sure it resolves/exists.

Be aware that checking that the domain resolves/exists could take time since your application would need to wait for a response from whatever service you use to check if it exists.